# Higher decoding latency on Snapdragon devices compared to Exynos devices with h264

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, qualcomm, exynos

I made the observation that for devices in the same price range, Snapdragon-based decoders can have a much higher decoding latency than Exynos-based decoders. This is most noticable when decoding h264 streams with the value "pic_order_cnt_type" inside the SPS set to 0 instead of 2.
I am wondering if you have also observed this behaviour and if there is any fix for that ( I have already opened an issue [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/hexagon-dsp-sdk/video/68285) but no response so far)

Some technical details:

I have built a simple example app that uses AMediaCodec to decode h264 streams. It uploads the "decoding latency", as a test result into a Firestore database. [code](https://github.com/Consti10/LiveVideo10ms)

Here is a comparison of the decoding latency for different h264 streams on a Pixel 4 (using snapdragon decoder) and a Samsung Galaxy Note 9 (using exynos decoder):

| Pixel 4 | Galaxy Note 9 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Pixel 4] | [image] |

As you can see, for the video called jetson/h264/2/test.h264, the decoding time on the snapdragon device is ~21 times higher than for the Samsung device. pic_order_cnt_type==0 for this stream. However, on other streams the difference in decoding time is insignificant. (they all use pic_order_cnt_type==2)

The main parameter determining if the snapdragon decoder enters a "low-latency decoding path" seems to be the value pic_order_cnt_type mentioned above.
If I understand the h264 specs correctly, if this value is set to 2 picture re-ordering is impossible (no buffered frames). If it is set to 0, picture re-ordering is possible, but not neccessarily used by the encoder. However, the snapdragon decoder doesn't differentiate between "possible" and "actually used by the encoder", leading to the big decoding latency difference.

I was able to reduce the decoding latency on snapdragon by manipulating the bitstream before sending it to the decoder (adding VUI with num_reorder_frames=0 and max_dec_frame_buffering=0) but it never results in 0 buffered frames, only less buffered frames.